# How do you set up a slave zone on zoneedit.com?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, bind, zoneedit

Simple question -- I'm trying to run a slave DNS server on zoneedit.com, with a primary serving runnning on my own bind9 instance on an Ubuntu server.

Zoneedit does not provide any support/how-to docs for configuring their servers as slaves to mine.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? Trying to get zoneedit to grab zone records from master DNS server. Complicated given that I'm sitting behind a cisco firewall; will likely have to allow tcp traffic on port 53 (something I don't want to do), and of course make sure no security holes in the zone allow.  Anyway, if you had success, let me know...thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that they do offer this product - http://www.zoneedit.com/tertiaryDNS.html but I can't find instructions on their public site.